# Get the number of true/false values in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, arraylist

I'm having an Array with properties `id` and `value`

```
 var arrayObj=  [
        {"id": 1, "value": true},
        {"id": 2, "value": false},
        {"id": 3, "value": true}
    ]
```

I need to get the number of objects that has the property `true`/`false`.
I'm using `Array.prototype.every()` but my logic is not working as intended as it seems. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm not displaying the count

```
function checkIfFalse(value, index, ar) {
     document.write(value + " ");
     if (value  === false)
         return true;
     else
        return false;
}

if (arrayObj.every(checkIfFalse)) {
    console.log("all are false");
}else {
    console.log("all are true");
}
```

Comment: remove the `document.write` use instead `console.log()`

Comment: the logic doesn't make sense to me.  not( all false) != all true

Comment: i suggest you can directly use a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `.every()` function is expecting being passed an function which will test each item of the array and return true or false. you would want something like:

```
  if (arrayObj.every(checkIfFalse)) {
                console.log("all are false");
  }

 function checkIfFalse(value, index, ar) {
   console.log('checking if' + index + ' from array is false');
   return value.value == false;
 }
```

so, `arrayObj.every(checkIfFalse)` will return `false` , because not all items are false

`.every()` is used to check if EVERY item of an array meets a certain condition, it sounds like you want to get a count of the number of items which meet a certain condition.  There is no way to do this without iterating through each item of the array and checking.  Thhis will be best if you just write your own for loop. ex:

```
function countItemsTrue(arry){
   var result = 0;
   for(x = 1; arry.length >= x; x++){
      if(arry[x].value === true){
        result++;
      }
   }
   return result;

}
```

then you would do

```
  var count = CountItemsTrue(arrayObj);
```

when it's written like this you can easily check if all are true without iterating all over just by checking:

```
  var allTrue = count == arrayObj.length;
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not using `.filter`?

```js
// Your array object
var arrayObj = [
  {"id": 1, "value": true},
  {"id": 2, "value": false},
  {"id": 3, "value": true}
];

// Count true items
var count = arrayObj.filter(function(s) { return s.value; }).length;

// Result
console.log("#True: " + count);
```

Comment: How can you use .filter to only find the false items?

Comment: @socca1157 Just add "!" prior to `s.value` to invert the boolean.   
`var count = arrayObj.filter(function(s) { return !s.value; }).length;`

Comment: I tried that, but wouldn't let me compare against a false or null value. I ended up converting the var to a string and doing a direct comparison that way. Thanks!

Comment: @socca1157 Really? That's weird. For me it works with `false` and `null`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
int falses=0,trues=0;
for(i=0;i<arrayObj.length;i++) {
    if(arrayObj[i].value) {
        trues++;
    } else {
        falses++;
    }
}
console.log('Trues: '+trues+' Falses:'+falses);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arrayObj = [{
  "id": 1,
  "value": true
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "value": false
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "value": true
}];

var trueCount = falseCount = 0;

arrayObj.forEach(function(object) {
  object.value === true ? trueCount++ : falseCount++;
});

console.log(trueCount, falseCount);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/pz29qrLe/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you actually want: you state a number of times that you want to count how many items have `false` values, yet your discussion of the code makes it sound like you only want to know if they *all* have false `value` properties.

If it's the first that you're after (the actual number of false values), you can get that by using `reduce` as follows:

```
var arrayObj = [
    { "id": 1, "value": true },
    { "id": 2, "value": false },
    { "id": 3, "value": true }
];

var numFalse = arrayObj.reduce(function(count, item) {
    return count + (item["value"] === false ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);
```

If it's the second (you want to know if *all* values are false), or you want to check if none or only some of the entries have `false` `value` entries, you can achieve those as follows:

```
var allFalse = numFalse == data.length,
    noneFalse = numFalse == 0,
    someFalse = numFalse > 0 && numFalse < data.length;
```

If you're not familiar with `reduce`, it works like this:

- The second parameter to `reduce` (a zero) sets the initial count to zero.
- For each item in the array, the function passed to `reduced` is called, with the first value being the current count and the second being the current item in the array.
- If the item's `value` property is `false`, we add one to the count, otherwise we add zero.
- At the end, `reduce` returns the final value of the count.

Comment: I like this , as it's a nice elegent solution and will surely get poster in trouble if it happens to be homework instead of an actual problem

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrayObj = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": true
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": true
  }
];

Array.prototype.numBoolean = function(condition) {
  var counter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i].value === condition) {
      counter++;
    }
  }
  return counter;
};

console.log(arrayObj.numBoolean(true));
console.log(arrayObj.numBoolean(false));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, use `array.forEach` instead of native iteration.

```js
var arrayObj = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": true
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": true
  }
];

var trueCount = 0,
  falseCount = 0;

arrayObj.forEach(function(index) {
  if (index.value == true) {
    trueCount++;
  } else if (index.value == false) {
    falseCount++;
  }
});

console.log('True Obj is ' + trueCount + ' False Obj is ' + falseCount);
```